Is being graded commutative a necessary condition on $A$ such that $H^*(A)$ is commutative?
If we consider any differential graded algebra $A^\bullet$, then its homology is a graded algebra, since the tensor product interacts well with homology.
A sufficient condidtion for the homology to be a commutative graded algebra is that $A^\bullet$ is graded commutative, i.e. that we have $ab=(-1)^{\deg a \cdot \deg b} ba$. The terminology “graded commutative dg-algebra” really makes it sound like this is also a necessary condition for $H^*(A^\bullet)$ to be commutative. Yet I've not found any comment on this, so I'm asking here (assuming I've missed the right place to look). Hence my question:
Is $H^*(A^\bullet)$ being commutative equivalent to $A^\bullet$ being graded commutative?

I think the singular cochains on a topological space are not graded commutative (only up to homotopy). This is how Steenrod operations come about.

@MarkGrant This is a good answer. IMO it would be quite reasonable to post it as an answer too, rather than just a comment.

@user509184 OK, I will do, thanks.

Every dg algebra is quasi-isomorphic to one which is free as a graded algebra: cobar construction of bar construction. In some sense, commutativity of cohomology tells you nothing about dg algebra.

Let $A^\bullet=C^\bullet(X;R)$, the singular cochains on a topological space $X$ with coefficients in a commutative ring $R$, endowed with the cup product of cochains. Given cochains $\varphi\in C^k(X;R)$ and $\psi\in C^\ell(X;R)$ their cup product $\varphi\cup\psi\in C^{k+\ell}(X;R)$ is the cochain whose value on a singular simplex $\sigma:\Delta^{k+\ell}\to X$ is given by
$$
(\varphi\cup\psi)(\sigma)=\varphi(\sigma|_{[v_0,\ldots, v_k]})\cdot\psi(\sigma|_{[v_k,\ldots , v_{k+\ell}]}).
$$
That is, $\varphi$ restricted to the front $k$-face multiplied by $\psi$ restricted to the back $\ell$-face.
This is usually not graded commutative, yet when you pass to homology you get the singular cohomology $H^\bullet(X;R)$, which is. See Hatcher Section 3.2, especially Theorem 3.14.

I think that it is commutative when $X$ is discrete, or more generally, totally disconnected.

@Z.M Right, because then every singular simplex is constant. I'll edit to reflect this.

I think that Mark Grant's answer is great, but if you want a simpler algebra, consider
$$
k\langle a_2, b_2, c_3 \rangle / (ac-ca, bc-cb, [a,[a,b]], [b, [a,b]]).
$$
(Subscripts indicate the degrees of the elements.) That is, this is the algebra is freely generated by $a$, $b$, and $c$, and then we impose relations that make $c$ central. We also want $a$ and $b$ to commute with $[a,b]$, explanation below. Note that $a$ and $b$ do not commute, even in the graded sense: the relations are generated by homogeneous elements of degree 5, so there is no relation between the degree 4 elements $ab$ and $ba$. Now put a differential on this:
$$
c \mapsto ab-ba.
$$
(The last two relations above are there so that this differential on $k\langle a,b,c \rangle$ will induce a differential on the quotient.) In cohomology, the classes induced by $a$ and $b$ will now commute, and I think that the cohomology algebra should be commutative. In fact I think it should just be polynomial on $[a]$ and $[b]$, if I use brackets to indicate cohomology classes. (Since the other answer is so good, I have not felt compelled to check the details.)

Even simpler example would be the tensor algebra of any contractible complex.

@mme: yes, thank you, fixed.

@DenisT simpler if the contractible complex is small enough, yes.

I think this does not quite work. I assume $d$ is extended freely by the Leibniz rule; but then $d(ac-ca) = a[a,b] - [a,b] a$, so I think $d$ does not descend to your quotient. I think it's OK if you also add the relations $[a, [a,b]] = [b, [a, b]] = 0$.

@mme: I think you're right.

You can make this example simpler by not taking the quotient by any relations at all. If  $A=k\langle a, b, c\rangle$ with differential $c \mapsto ab-ba$, then $H(A) \cong k[a,b]$ and in fact $A$ is a cofibrant replacement of $k[a,b]$ in the category of dg algebras. The easiest way to see this is that a polynomial ring is Koszul, and $A$ is the Koszul resolution of $k[a,b]$ (the cobar construction on the Koszul dual coalgebra, which is the exterior coalgebra on two generators).
